# Caching issues with my router?

Tags: ios, iphone, wordpress, caching

I'm working from home today, and I've been trying to edit the stylesheet in my wordpress installation for the last hour, with no changes reflecting on the website.

**I have tried:**

- Firefox, chrome, safari, and opera on my Mac
- Hard refreshing with F5, and alt+refresh button in browser
- Looking at it on my iphone
- switching off the wifi, and using 3G on my iphone (This Worked)!!!

So I'm wondering if there is a way for my router to cache something? Since it doesn't seem to just be my one computer, but my wifi in the house in general. What sort of things can I do to get this to un-cache??

This is my site:
http://www.christmaslightsinstallation.ca/

The sidebar headings should have a green background. I see this on my phone now using 3G, but not on my computer.

Comment: Have you tried other machines on the wifi network in your home?

Comment: I've tried my iphone, and also my laptop which is running windows 7. Still can't see the changes on any of them.

Comment: What model of router, and what firmware revision are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Please check following issues:

- If you are using CDN like cloudflare or maxcdn then please login and delete cache
- Please check if your hosting provider is using the static cache or not then try to login cpanel and clear cache.
- Check if your server/hosting using any proxy cache and try to delete them.
- Disable all of caching plugin of your wordpress installation

Good luck and please show here if it still happen.